# How to request another action in minion

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I'm trying to run a controller action from command line. The php code is written in Kohana 3.3. Kohana officially says I have to use minion task processor. How do I include my action in this module?

Comment: have you tried HMVC calls? http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/requests#requests

Answer (score 0):

You can call the minion controller from command line like this (as of Kohana 3.3):

```sh
$ php index.php --uri=minion --task={task}
```

Every task goes inside `classes/task`, as explained here https://github.com/kohana/minion#writing-your-own-tasks

Make sure to enable the minion module in the bootstrap

Before the minion module, you'd have to use controllers, and some server related stuff would be unavailable, but you would do as in the browser

```sh
$ php index.php --uri="control/do/action"
```